# SQLAlchemy: @event.listens_for(Engine, 'handle_error') always re-raises the error

Tags: mysql, error-handling, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to catch errors such as "database does not exist" or "table does not exist".
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine 

class MultiTenantSQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):  # type: ignore
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        @event.listens_for(Engine, 'handle_error')
        def receive_handle_error(exception_context):
            print("listen for the 'handle_error' event")
            print(exception_context)

db = MultiTenantSQLAlchemy(flask_app)
db.session.execute('SELECT * FROM `table_that_does_not_exit`').fetchone()
```

Output:

```
listen for the 'handle_error' event
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.ExceptionContextImpl object at 0x1140c5710>
```

but I still get this exception:

```
ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'somedb.some_fake_table' doesn't exist")
```

How can I suppress the exception?

Answer (score 0):

you can use try except and catch the error

```
from sqlalchemy import exc
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine 

class MultiTenantSQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):  # type: ignore
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        @event.listens_for(Engine, 'handle_error')
        def receive_handle_error(exception_context):
            print("listen for the 'handle_error' event")
            print(exception_context)

db = MultiTenantSQLAlchemy(flask_app)

try:
  db.session.execute('SELECT * FROM `table_that_does_not_exit`').fetchone()
except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
  pass # do something intelligent here
```

Comment: I can't do that because I need to catch this type of error in a hundred places.

Comment: it is normal for all languages to use try catch around every critical section, this is teh only way to catch the errror. bas programmers make on big try catch, but that is as i said bad programmg

Comment: @MikeFurlender You could subclass `db.session` and override the `execute` method, wrapping  a call to `super().execute()` in a `try/except`.